# How do I use a loop to find the lowest score in an array and all scores > or = 100?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Here's what I have, the application is to determine the average, lowest, and perfect of an array of scores. I figured the average but I try to figure the perfect scores I don't get any output? I can't see where I went wrong? I am also not exactly sure how to find the lowest of all scores. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? and/or how to use a loop to find the lowest of the scores?

```
    int[] scores = new int[10]; 
    int score = 0; 
    int count = 0; 
    int total = 0;
    final int QUIT = 909; 
    final int MAX = 10; 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.print("Please enter your scores: "); 
    score = input.nextInt(); 

    while(count < MAX && score != QUIT) 
    { 
    if(score != QUIT) 
    { 
        scores[count] = score; 

        total += scores[count];
        System.out.print("Enter next quiz score or enter " + QUIT + " to finish: "); 
        score = input.nextInt(); } count++; 
    } 

    System.out.println("The scores entered were: ");

            for(int x = 0; x < count; ++x) 
            System.out.print(scores[x] + " \n");

    System.out.println("The average of all scores: " + (total * 1.0 / count));
    System.out.println("Your lowest score: "); //not sure how to loop through to find the lowest score
    System.out.println("All perfect scores: ");

        for(int x = 0; x >= scores.length; ++x) 
        {
            if(scores[x] >= 100)
        {
        System.out.print(scores[x]); //not getting any output and I dont know why
```

Comment: How would you do it if you were given the numbers on a sheet of paper, handed a pencil, and told to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a new field called `minimum` and set it to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

In each iteration of your while loop calulate

```
minimum = Math.min (minimum, score);
```

Also

```
while(count < MAX && score != QUIT) 
{ 
  if(score != QUIT) // this is not needed
```

Also

```
for(int x = 0; x >= scores.length; ++x)
```

will never work so try

```
for(int x = 0; x < scores.length; ++x)
```

Comment: Normally `minimum` should be set to the maximum negative value.  Only use zero if you have an unsigned data type.

Comment: Confusion wins :) If you want to find smaller values, initialize with a value bigger than any actual value (or the first actual value) so it's guaranteed to be overriden. => `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. It would stay forever at `MIN_VALUE` because there is nothing that can be more `Math.min()` than that.

Comment: @zapl Not enough coffee this morning.  You are soo right.  And all meaningless unless the OP checks this for value in her code.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int x = 0; x >= scores.length; ++x)
```

Try x< scores.length instead. The way you've written it, x starts at zero and the loop repeats while x>scores.length, which it never is, so nothing ever happens.

Comment: It works and makes sense. Loops are still tricky for me I guess I just did't really look at it hard enough. Thank you